Is it true that even the lowest person in Jannah will actually have far more than times this Dunya?
Salam aleikum brothers and sisters.
I have heard some imams say that the lowest person in Jannah will in reality have so much more than this entire Dunya and everything in it and that Allah SWT just uses the example of 10 times this Dunya and everything in it to give our extremely limited brains a tidy idea of how much he will actually get. How true is this?

It is true as it is a Saheeh Hadeeth in Saheeh Muslim:

Abdullah b. Mas'ud reported that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: I
know the last of the inhabitants of Fire to be taken out therefrom,
and the last of the inhabitants of Paradise to enter it. A man will
come out of the Fire crawling. Then Allah, the Blessed and Exalted
will say to him: Go and enter Paradise. So he would come to it and it
would appear to him as if it were full. He would go back and say: O my
Lord! I found it full. Allah, the Blessed and Exalted, would say to
him: Go and enter Paradise. He would come and perceive as if it were
full. He would return and say: O my Lord! I found it full. Allah would
say to him: Go and enter Paradise, for there is for you the like of
the world and ten times like it, or for you is ten times the like of
this world. He (the narrator) said. He (that man) would say: Art
Thou making a fun of me? or Art Thou laughing at me. though Thou art
the King? He (the narrator) said: I saw the Messenger of Allah laugh
till his front teeth were visible. And it was said: That would be the
lowest rank among the inhabitants of Paradise.

https://sunnah.com/muslim:186a

I think you misunderstood me. I was asking if its true that in reality he will have far more than 10 times this Dunya and everything in it

Wa Alaikum Assalam wa rahamtullah wa barakatu,
Yes, that’s true. The hadith about the lowest person in Jannah receiving "ten times this dunya" is a way of conveying the unimaginable and incomprehensible rewards of Paradise. It’s not meant to be taken literally, but as an approximation to help our limited understanding. The reality is that Allah's rewards in Jannah are far beyond anything we can conceive, and the "ten times" is just a figure used to give us a sense of its greatness. In short, Allah's blessings in Jannah are infinitely greater than anything we can imagine.
there is another hadith that talk about this
the prophet pbh said
bdullah ibn Mas’ud reported:

The Prophet, peace and blessings be upon him, said, “Verily, I know who will be the last to come out of the Hellfire and the last to enter Paradise. He is a man who will come out of the Hellfire crawling. Allah will say to him: Go and enter Paradise. The man will go out but imagine it is full, so he will return and say: O Lord, I have found it full. Allah will say: Go and enter Paradise and you will have as much as the world and ten times more. The man will say: Do You mock me or laugh at me while you are the King?”I saw Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) (while saying that) smiling that his premolar teeth became visible. It is said that will be the lowest in degree amongst the people of Paradise.
Source: Ṣaḥīḥ al-Bukhārī 6571, Ṣaḥīḥ Muslim 186
Grade: Muttafaqun Alayhi (authenticity agreed upon) according to Al-Bukhari and Muslim


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
